# How to store Kubernetes pods logs directly on local machine?

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kubernetes, kibana

As logs go away as soon as pods crashes, I would like to store them directly on my local machine. I don't want to use GCE. Also I would have multiple nodes of a service, so `HostPath` will not be of any use.

`kubectl logs <pod-name> > log.txt` will just capture a snapshot. I want the complete logs to be persistent on my local machine.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by multiple nodes of a service? Do you mean replicas? Log get persistent on Linux box even if there is a pod crash. If you have access to the machine, then the logs will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Logs are already on nodes in `/var/lib/docker/containers/CONTAINER_ID/CONTAINER_ID-json.log`

For collecting them you can use fluent-bit. The easiest approach would be using kubernetes to manage fluent-bit - run daemon set with host path volumes.

Here is helm chart that can do it for you: https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/fluent-bit